# ASP.NEt - Benefit of async calls to DB

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous

In an ASP.NET application, what would be the real benefit to make async calls to the database?

Since each request is served by a thread, whether the thread has a blocking call or it is released to serve other users (while waiting for the async call to return), shouldn't make any difference, assuming a reasonably sized thread pool.

Or, am I missing something?

Comment: I guess you would only see the benefit inside the DLL making the call. In theory you could make a couple of calls from your code and not have to wait for them serially.

Comment: yes, for scenarios where I need several queries to formulate a response, it makes sense. But in a common scenarios where requests are essentially a DB request, or a few sequential ones, I don't see where the would be a benefit.